# How do I find a basis for the following subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm unsure how to do the following problem: Find a basis of the following subspace of $R^4$. W = all vectors of the form $(a,b,c,d)$ where $a+b-c+d=0$. Any help would be great, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one equation in four-dimensional space, so the subspace in question has three dimensions. Three linearly independent vectors satisfying the relation would do it. For instance:
$$
(1,0,1,0),(0,1,1,0),(0,0,1,1)
$$